# How to solve these two differential equations

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, symbolic, differentials

I have two differential equations and I try to use function `DSolve` to solve them together.

```
DSolve[{r^2*A''[r] + 2*r*A'[r] - 2 A[r] + lambda^2*r^2*A[r] + 
2 lambda*r^2*dd'[r] == 0, 
r*dd''[r] + 2 dd'[r] + 3 lambda^2*r*dd[r] + 2 lambda*r*A'[r] + 
4 lambda*A[r] == 0}, {A, dd}, r]
```

There are two functions as `A` and `dd`. But it failed.

I try to use Maple software to solve it and it successes and needs little time.

The Maple code:

```
sol3 := r^2*diff(A(r), r, r) + 2*r*diff(A(r), r) - 2*A(r) + lambda^2*r^2*A(r) +2*lambda*r^2*diff(dd(r), r) = 0

sol4 := r*diff(dd(r), r, r) + 2*diff(dd(r), r) + 3*lambda^2*r*dd(r) + 2*lambda*r*diff(A(r), r) + 4*lambda*A(r) = 0

dsolve({sol3, sol4})
```

Therefore, the equations has solutions. I want to know whether Mathematica can solve it and how to do it. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 6):

**Edited to derive simpler expression for `dd`**

The symbolic solution requested in the Question is obtained as follows.

```
eq1 = Expand[(r^2*A''[r] + 2*r*A'[r] - 2 A[r] + lambda^2*r^2*A[r] + 
    2 lambda*r^2*dd'[r])/r^2];
(* lambda^2 A[r] - 2 A[r]/r^2 + 2 A'[r]/r + 2 lambda dd'[r] + A''[r] *)
eq2 = Expand[(r*dd''[r] + 2 dd'[r] + 3 lambda^2*r*dd[r] + 
    2 lambda*r*A'[r] + 4 lambda*A[r])/r];
(* (4 lambda A[r])/r + 3 lambda^2 dd[r] + 2 lambda A'[r] + 2 dd'[r]/r + dd''[r] *)
```

Combine the two expressions to obtain an expression for `dd` in terms of `A`

```
eqdd = -Subtract @@ First[Eliminate[{eq1 == 0, eq2 == 0, D[eq1, r] == 0}, 
    {dd'[r], dd''[r]}]]
(* -6*lambda^2*A[r]/r - 6*lambda^3*dd[r] - 3*lambda^2*A'[r] + 4*A''[r]/r + A'''[r] *)
```

and an expression for `A` alone and solve it.

```
eqA = Subtract @@ First[Eliminate[{D[eqdd, r] == 0, eq1 == 0}, dd'[r]]]
(* 3*lambda^4*r*A[r] - 4*A''[r]/r + 4*A'''[r] + r*A''''[r] *)

sA = DSolveValue[eqA == 0, A[r], r]
(*   (E^((-1)^(3/4) 3^(1/4) lambda r) (I + (-3)^(1/4) lambda r) C[1])/r^2 
   + (E^((-3)^(1/4) lambda r) (-I + (-1)^(3/4) 3^(1/4) lambda r) C[2])/r^2 
   + (E^(-(-1)^(3/4) 3^(1/4) lambda r) (-I + (-3)^(1/4) lambda r) C[3])/r^2
   + (E^(-(-3)^(1/4) lambda r) (I + (-1)^(3/4) 3^(1/4) lambda r) C[4])/r^2 *)
```

Finally, substitute `A` into `eqdd` and solve it.

```
sdd = Solve[Simplify[eqdd /. A -> Function[{r}, sA]] == 0, dd[r]][[1, 1]] // Values
(* -(1/(lambda r^3)) (E^((-1)^(3/4) 3^(1/4) lambda r) (I + (-3)^(1/4) lambda r) C[1] + 
    E^((-3)^(1/4) lambda r) (-I + (-1)^(3/4) 3^(1/4) lambda r) C[2] + 
    E^(-(-1)^(3/4) 3^(1/4) lambda r) (-I + (-3)^(1/4) lambda r) C[3] +
    E^(-(-3)^(1/4) lambda r) (I + (-1)^(3/4) 3^(1/4) lambda r) C[4]) *)
```

as requested.

**Addendum: Eliminating complex numbers from the solution.**

It often is desirable not to have complex numbers in the solutions of real ODEs.  This can be accomplished by converting exponentials to trigonometric and hyperbolic functions, performing a complex expansion, and replacing the existing constants of integration by constants that absorb the complex numbers.

```
sA1 = Collect[ComplexExpand@ExpToTrig@sA, {r, Cos[_] Cosh[_], Cos[_] Sinh[_], 
    Sin[_] Cosh[_], Sin[_] Sinh[_]}, Simplify];
Cases[sA1, Cos[_] Cosh[_] z_ | Sin[_] Cosh[_] z_ | Cos[_] Sinh[_] z_ | 
    Sin[_] Sinh[_] z_ -> z, Infinity, 4];
cf = Solve[Thread[{c1, c2, c3, c4} == %], {C[1], C[2], C[3], C[4]}] // Flatten;
sA2 = Collect[sA1 /. cf, {r, Cos[_] Cosh[_], Cos[_] Sinh[_], Sin[_] Cosh[_], 
    Sin[_] Sinh[_]}, Simplify]
(* (1/(r^2))(c1 Cos[(3^(1/4) lambda r)/Sqrt[2]] Cosh[(3^(1/4) lambda r)/ Sqrt[2]] + 
             c2 Cosh[(3^(1/4) lambda r)/Sqrt[2]] Sin[(3^(1/4) lambda r)/Sqrt[2]] + 
             c3 Cos[(3^(1/4) lambda r)/Sqrt[2]] Sinh[(3^(1/4) lambda r)/ Sqrt[2]] + 
             c4 Sin[(3^(1/4) lambda r)/Sqrt[2]] Sinh[(3^(1/4) lambda r)/Sqrt[2]]) + 
   (1/r)(-((3^(1/4) (c2 + c3) lambda Cos[(3^(1/4) lambda r)/Sqrt[2]] Cosh[(
  3^(1/4) lambda r)/Sqrt[2]])/Sqrt[2]) + 
          (3^(1/4) (c1 - c4) lambda Cosh[(3^(1/4) lambda r)/Sqrt[2]] Sin[(
  3^(1/4) lambda r)/Sqrt[2]])/Sqrt[2] - 
          (3^(1/4) (c1 + c4) lambda Cos[(3^(1/4) lambda r)/Sqrt[2]] Sinh[(
  3^(1/4) lambda r)/Sqrt[2]])/Sqrt[2] - 
          (3^(1/4) (c2 - c3) lambda Sin[(3^(1/4) lambda r)/Sqrt[2]] Sinh[(
  3^(1/4) lambda r)/Sqrt[2]])/Sqrt[2]) *)

sdd2 = Collect[ComplexExpand@ExpToTrig@sdd /. cf, {r, Cos[_] Cosh[_], 
    Cos[_] Sinh[_], Sin[_] Cosh[_], Sin[_] Sinh[_]}, Simplify]
(* (1/(r^2))((3^(1/4) (c2 + c3) Cos[(3^(1/4) lambda r)/Sqrt[2]] Cosh[(
   3^(1/4) lambda r)/Sqrt[2]])/Sqrt[2] + 
            (3^(1/4) (-c1 + c4) Cosh[(3^(1/4) lambda r)/Sqrt[2]] Sin[(
   3^(1/4) lambda r)/Sqrt[2]])/Sqrt[2] + 
            (3^(1/4) (c1 + c4) Cos[(3^(1/4) lambda r)/Sqrt[2]] Sinh[(
   3^(1/4) lambda r)/Sqrt[2]])/Sqrt[2] + 
            (3^(1/4) (c2 - c3) Sin[(3^(1/4) lambda r)/Sqrt[2]] Sinh[(
   3^(1/4) lambda r)/Sqrt[2]])/Sqrt[2]) + 
   (1/(r^3))(-((c1 Cos[(3^(1/4) lambda r)/Sqrt[2]] Cosh[(3^(1/4) lambda 
   r)/Sqrt[2]])/lambda) - 
               (c2 Cosh[(3^(1/4) lambda r)/Sqrt[2]] Sin[(3^(1/4) lambda 
   r)/Sqrt[2]])/lambda - 
               (c3 Cos[(3^(1/4) lambda r)/Sqrt[2]] Sinh[(3^(1/4) lambda 
   r)/Sqrt[2]])/lambda - 
               (c4 Sin[(3^(1/4) lambda r)/Sqrt[2]] Sinh[(3^(1/4) lambda 
   r)/Sqrt[2]])/lambda) *)
```

For convenience, the solutions can be plotted for one non-zero `c` at a time.

```
Plot[Evaluate[Replace[sA2, {{c1 -> 1}, {c2 -> 1}, {c3 -> 1}, {c4 -> 1}}, Infinity] 
    /. {c1 -> 0, c2 -> 0, c3 -> 0, c4 -> 0, lambda -> 1}], {r, 0, 5}, 
    ImageSize -> Large, AxesLabel -> {r, A}, LabelStyle -> {15, Bold, Black}, 
    PlotLegends -> Placed[{c1, c2, c3, c4}, {.3, .8}]]
```

[image]

```
Plot[Evaluate[Replace[sdd2, {{c1 -> 1}, {c2 -> 1}, {c3 -> 1}, {c4 -> 1}}, Infinity] 
    /. {c1 -> 0, c2 -> 0, c3 -> 0, c4 -> 0, lambda -> 1}], {r, 0, 5}, 
    ImageSize -> Large, AxesLabel -> {r, dd}, LabelStyle -> {15, Bold, Black}, 
    PlotLegends -> Placed[{c1, c2, c3, c4}, {.6, .8}]]
```

[image]

Comment: +1. In the hands of a great chef .

Comment: The question did not pose that A has to be differentiable four times. There are no conditions given to solve for all the constants. Problem is to solve this with minimal additional openness not to derive a polynomial over the Complexes. Great is, this uses only DSolve. The problem is totally underdetermined.

Answer (score 1):

```
ClearAll[A, r, dd, sol3, sol4, lambda]
sol3 = r^2*D[A[r], r, r] + 2*r*D[A[r], r] - 2*A[r] + 
  lambda^2*r^2*A[r] + 2*lambda*r^2*D[dd[r], r]

sol4 = r*D[dd[r], r, r] + 2*D[dd[r], r] + 3*lambda^2*r*dd[r] + 
  2*lambda*r*D[A[r], r] + 4*lambda*A[r]
lambda = 0;

s = NDSolve[{sol3 == 0, sol4 == 0, A[1] == 1, A'[1] == 1, dd[1] == 1, 
   dd'[1] == 1}, {A, dd}, {r, 1, 2}]
```

[image: output]

```
Plot[{A[r], dd[r]} /. s, {r, 1, 2}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Plot of the solutions]

For

```
lambda = 0.5;
```

[image]

If the integration interval is extented towards zero the singularity at r==0 get important and influences, dominates the solution:

lambda = 5.0;
s2 = NDSolve[{sol3 == 0, sol4 == 0, A[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S6T7N.png) == 1, A'[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S6T7N.png) == 1, dd[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S6T7N.png) == 1,
dd'[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S6T7N.png) == 1}, {A, dd}, {r, MachinePrecision, 5}]
Plot[{A[r], dd[r]} /. s2, {r, 0.2, 2}, PlotRange -> All,
PlotStyle -> Automatic]
[image]

Mathematica has no `DSolve` solution since the details are not given in the question. The boundary conditions for this solution are taken by choice. They can be selected from a wide range. Same is true for lambda.

```
lambda = 5.0;
s2 = DSolve[{sol3 == 0, sol4 == 0, A[1] == 0, A'[1] == .1, dd[1] == 2,
    dd'[1] == 1}, {A, dd}, {r, 0.1, 5}]
(*{{A -> Function[{r}, -(0.0333333/r^2) + 0.0333333 r], 
  dd -> Function[{r}, 3 - 1/r]}}*)

Plot[{A[r], dd[r]} /. s2, {r, 0.1, 5}, PlotRange -> All, 
 PlotStyle -> Automatic]
```

[image: output]

Comment: Your `DSolve` answer is valid only for `lambda = 0`, as can be verified by `Simplify[{sol3, sol4} /. s2] // Chop`.

Comment: +1. `NDSolve` and/or `ParametricNDSolve` are a natural approach to such problems.